# getting total popup data when even that crossed window width

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

here is my task.

I want to print my popup data but here my problem is I can print popup that had cover only window (actually my popup is very large than window ) but needs to print total popup data . can anyone know about it 
 Here is my code (whatever I got from the internet)

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg print" id="printview" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <!--Content-->
        <div class="modal-content popup-style">
            <!--Body-->
            <div class="modal-body">
                 <div class="table-responsive" id="md-table-template">
              <table md-colresize="md-colresize" class="table md-table table-data4 tablestyle">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    <th>Care Plan Name </th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>Category </th>
                    <th>Start Date </th>
                    <th> Present on Admission</th>
                    <th><a href="javascript:window.print()"><i class="fa fa-print color-blue"  aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a></th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                   <tr ng-show="noResidentsData"><td colspan="6" >NO RECORDS FOUND</td></tr>
                  <tr ng-repeat-start="c in residentCareplans" class="md-table-content-row class_{{c.ResidentCarePlanID}}" ng-style="{'text-decoration':(c.CarePlanStatusID==constants.CAREPLAN_STATUS.RETRACT?'line-through':'none')}">
                    <td><a ng-click="expand = !expand; "><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></td>
                    <td ng-class="customClass[h.field]" class="md-table-content">{{c.ProblemDescription}}</td>
                    <td ng-class="customClass[h.field]" class="md-table-content">{{c.CarePlanTypeID == 1 ? 'Ongoing':(c.CarePlanTypeID == 2)?'Acute':'Discharge'}}</td>
                    <td ng-class="customClass[h.field]" class="md-table-content">{{c.CategoryDescription}}</td>
                    <td ng-class="customClass[h.field]" class="md-table-content">{{ (c.StartDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy') }}</td>
                    <td ng-class="customClass[h.field]" class="md-table-content"><i ng-if="c.PresentOnAdmission  == true" class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
                    <td ng-class="customClass[h.field]" class="md-table-content">&nbsp;</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr ng-repeat-end="" >
                    <td colspan="7" class="tableviewexpand">
                      <div class="col-md-12  scrolldata">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <p>Diagnosis:</p>
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="col-md-6"></div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                              <span class="pull-right"><input  type="checkbox" value="true"> Include Inactive components</span>
                              <!--<span class="pull-right"><input  type="checkbox" value="true">Include Care Plan Notes</span>-->
                              <span class="pull-right" ><input  type="checkbox" value="true"  ng-model="includenotes" ng-click="getNotes();">Include Care Plan Notes</span>



                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-12 gray-bg-1">

                            <table class="table-goals" width="100%">
                              <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                  <td>
                                    <p>Goal:</p>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>
                                    <p>Interventions:</p>
                                  </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr ng-repeat="c in careplan.careGoals track by $index">
                                  <td>
                                    <p>{{c.GoalDescription}}</p>
                                    <table width="100%" class="data-dispay">
                                      <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="left" valign="top">Review Date:</td>
                                          <td align="left" valign="top">{{c.GoalReviewDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                          <td align="left" valign="top"> Start Date:</td>
                                          <td align="left" valign="top">{{c.GoalStartDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                      </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                  </td>
                                  <td>

                                    <div class="loop-div" ng-repeat="i in c.rcp_interventions track by $index">
                                      <p>{{i.InterventionDescription}}</p>
                                      <table width="100%" class="data-dispay">
                                        <tbody>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top">Review Date:</td>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top">{{i.InterventionReviewDate | date:'MM/dd/yyyy' }}</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top">Roles:</td>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top"><span ng-repeat="r in i.rcp_interventionroles">{{r.rolebase.RoleName}}, </span></td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top">Frequency:</td>
                                            <td align="left" valign="top"><span ng-repeat="f in i.rcp_interventionfrequency.schedules">{{f.scheduletype.UnitDescription}} </span>                                              </td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                      </table>

                                    </div>



                                  </td>
                                </tr>

                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                          </div>

                          <div ng-show="includenotes"><p>Care Plan Notes: </p>
                          <span ng-repeat="list in notes">{{list.Text}}, </span>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
```

and css:

```
@media print
{
    .no-print { display: none; }
    .print { display: block; }
}
```

and javascript:

```
<script>
  function Quoter($scope) {
    $scope.clientName="TBC";
    $scope.projectName="TBC";
    $scope.templateNames="";
    $scope.amountOfTemplates=1;
    $scope.timePerTemplate=4;  
    $scope.initialSetup=8;
    $scope.javascript=10;
    $scope.responsiveIncrease=35;
    $scope.testingIncrease=30;
    $scope.aaAccessibility=30;


    $scope.standardTotal=function(){
        var totSum=$scope.amountOfTemplates * $scope.timePerTemplate + $scope.initialSetup + $scope.javascript;            
        return totSum;
    };

    $scope.percentageOfTotal=function(){
        var percent=Math.ceil($scope.responsiveIncrease/100 * $scope.standardTotal());
        return percent;        
    };

    $scope.sumResponsive= function() {
        if($scope.responsiveBoolean){
        var resHrs = Math.ceil($scope.responsiveIncrease/100 * $scope.standardTotal());
        }else{
            resHrs = 0;
        }
        return resHrs;
     };

    $scope.sumTesting= function() {
        if($scope.testingBoolean){
        var testHrs = Math.ceil($scope.testingIncrease/100 * $scope.standardTotal());
        }else{
            testHrs = 0;
        }
        return testHrs;
     };

    $scope.sumAccessibility= function() {
        if($scope.aaAccessibilityBoolean){
        var accessibilityHrs = Math.ceil($scope.aaAccessibility/100 * $scope.standardTotal());
        }else{
            accessibilityHrs = 0;
        }
        return accessibilityHrs;
     };


    $scope.total= function() {
       var totComp = Math.ceil($scope.standardTotal() + $scope.sumResponsive() + $scope.sumTesting() + $scope.sumAccessibility());
        return totComp;
     };

    $scope.removeTodo = function() {
        $scope.todos.pop();

  };

    $scope.addTodo = function() {
        $scope.todos.push({text:$scope.todoText, done:false});
        $scope.todoText = '';
  };

    //$scope.nameTemplates = function() {
      //  if(templateNames!=""){
        //    alert("true");
        //} 
  //};
}
</script>
```

Comment: where is your print method defined?

Comment: href="javascript:window.print()" u can see this method in html

Comment: I think you are looking for how to print the content inside a modal popup?